# How to draw flowchart for if condition within nested loops?

Tags: loops, branch-and-bound, data-flow-analysis

Please find my program logic as below :

[image]

Please find my flowchart for the above program logic as below:

[image]

My superior asked me correct the flowchart. But I couldn't identify my mistakes.

Please guide me to correct my flowchart in correct manner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose you end up in stmt-2. Where do you go from there?

Comment: @ ttnick: Yes. Your question is correct. Can I give link from stmt-2 and stmt-4 to while loop starting point. Is it correct?

Comment: From stmt-2, you certainly want to execute stmt-3, the next if, and stmt-5 before you go back to the condition check of the loop.

Comment: @ ttnick: You are correct. What is wrong in the flowchart? How can I modify the link. Please guide me. Thanks..

Comment: @ ttnick: I modified the flowchart as per your suggestions and update it by editing the question. Please go through it and guide me if any corrections required. Thanks.

Comment: stmt-2 and 4 and 6 are still terminal nodes in this flowchart but you want only the (Stop) node to be terminal (no outgoing edges). I think it should be pretty clear where they should link to.

Comment: @ ttnick: Yes. Your suggestion is correct. Based on the program stmt-2 and 4 and 6 don't have else part and I modified the flowchart as per your suggestion and update it by editing the question. Please go through it and guide me if any corrections required. Thanks.

Comment: Where to go when an `if` condition is false?

Comment: @reinierpost: I modified the flowchart as per your suggestions and update it by editing the question. Please go through it and guide me if any corrections required. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a homework correction service. We ask that you ask one question, preferably one that is useful for many others, and leave it up with the answers, so others can find the answer to that same question here, instead of changing the question as your insight progresses.

Comment: @ reinierpost: ok.. Thanks for your suggestions..